# on android 8: why not occurs stop when updates UI in child-thread?

Tags: android, thread-safety

on android 8: why not occurs stop when updates UI in child-thread?
I searched for a long time but no answer for me. It occurred on android 7 and 6.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView textContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textContent = findViewById(R.id.textContent);

        Button changeTextButton = findViewById(R.id.change_text);
        changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }    

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.change_text:
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textContent.setText("Nice to meet you !");
                    }
                }).start();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change UI in another thread, my suggestion is use runOnUiThread replace below code
From :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textContent.setText("Nice to meet you !");
                    }
                }).start();
```

to :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               textContent.setText("Nice to meet you !");
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change UI elements from child/worker thread. Simply do following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.change_text:
            textContent.setText("Nice to meet you !");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Since `onClick()` will be executed on main thread

Comment: I know that ,but there is no error when i run on a phone with android version 8.0. Why ? you can have a try.

Comment: HuaWei Mate 10 or simulator